# Get out the value of a variable in each observation to a macro variable

Tags: macros, sas

I have a table called `term_table` containing the below columns

`comp`, `term_type`, `term`, `score`, `rank`

I go through every observation and at each obs, I want to store the value of variable rank to a macro variable called `curr_r`. The code I created below does not work

```
Data Work.term_table;
 input  Comp $
        Term_type $
        Term $
        Score
        Rank
      ;
 datalines;
 comp1 term_type1 A 1 1  
 comp2 term_type2 A 2 10
 comp3 term_type3 A 3 20
 comp4 term_type4 B 4 20
 comp5 term_type5 B 5 40
 comp6 term_type6 B 6 100
 ;
Run;

    %local j;
    DATA tmp;
    SET term_table;
    LENGTH freq 8;

    BY &by_var term_type term;
    RETAIN freq;

    CALL SYMPUT('curr_r', rank);
    IF first.term THEN DO;
        %do j = 1 %to &curr_r;
                         do some thing
                    %end;
    END;
RUN;
```

Could you help me to solve the problem

Thanks a lot

Hung

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call symput statement does create the macro var &curr_r with the value of rank, but it is not available until after the data step.

However, I don't think you need to create the macro var &curr_r. I don't think a macro is needed at all.

I think the below should work: (Untested)

```
DATA tmp;
 SET term_table;
 LENGTH freq 8;

 BY &by_var term_type term;
 RETAIN freq;

 IF first.term THEN DO;
  do j = 1 to rank;
   <do some thing>
  end;
 END;
RUN;
```

If you needed to use the rank from a prior obs, use the LAG function.

```
Start=Lag(rank);
```

To store each value of RANK in a macro variable, the below will do that:

```
Proc Sql noprint;
 select count(rank)
 into :cnt
 from term_table;

 %Let cnt=&cnt;

 select rank
 into :curr_r1 - :curr_r&cnt
 from term_table;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks alot. In the term_table, assume the term 'A' has 3 values of RANK: 1, 10, 20. Now assume I am at obs term=A and rank=10. I need to do a loop: "Do J=2 to 10". IF I am at term=A, rank = 20 I need to do a loop: "Do j=11 TO 20). THat means I should store the previous rank and the current rank at each obs to do the loop. Could you give me any suggestion. Hung

Comment: Hi, Yes, finally I found that I do not need macro variables to solve my problem. THanks a lot

Comment: Happy to help...i updated your answer with some sample data, change if necessary. Add your additional question to your original, it'll make the answers make sense. The sample data makes it easier to help...